# AsymmetricGridView with custom design

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i want to draw `recycleview` like this image with different categories items number got them from web service.

Problem: when use normal `setLayoutManager` method like:

```
categoryRecyleView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 2));
categoryRecyleView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));

categoryRecyleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
categoryRecyleView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

because number of of column not fixed

so how i can do this ?

[image: ie]

Comment: How About using [**`FlexboxLayoutManager`**](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview)